# Sending public transactions with Web3j's Quorum client

Tags: java, web3-java, quorum

How does one send **public transactions** using Web3j's quorum client?

Currently I am sending private transactions with this code, and even if my "privyFor" list is empty it is sent as a **private transaction**.

```
HttpService httpService = BuildHttpService(NODE);

Quorum quorum = Quorum.build(httpService);



ArrayList<String> privyFor = new ArrayList<>();



// note that privyFor is an empty list

ClientTransactionManager transactionManager = new ClientTransactionManager(quorum, ACCOUNT_ADDRESS, privyFor);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we do not set the **privateFor** value, this transaction is deemed public, which means all nodes will receive this transaction and see the value inside the contract object.

I created a public transaction I have

```
return instance.set(65, {privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="]});
```

Remove it to

```
return instance.set(70, );
```

And the transaction will be public to all in network [image]

You can see my 70 value transaction is visible to all node peers .

Or you can see geth network coding too. I am attaching screenshot below .

[image]